# How to interpret ×/ ÷ for the confidence intervals? How to propagate these type of intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm not an expert in statistics. Currently, I'm working on some allometric equations and in the literature I found:

[image]

According to the foot note in the table (and as intuition would dictate) the 95% confidence interval for let's say "*All non-hoppers*" would be [6.2/1.12, 6.2*1.12]. Hence, the limit become [5.54, 6.94].

1. This seems unaccurate, lazy, naive, and, over all,  worng, but can this be "translated" to: 6.24±0.7 ?
2. If the answer to the first question is "no" (which I know it would be), what if I need to propagate these confidence limits by multiplying this parameter with another of the style a±b.

I guess I could use what is explained in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXbeWykVdq4
but, that explanation applies for when we have confidence limits of the style a±b. What should I do with confidence limits of ×/÷ ?

Thank you,

^.^

Comment: Hey Kale, welcome to the site! These types of intervals are useful for data which are strictly positive, as these tend to be skewed and, most importantly, would have negative intervals if we used the $\pm$ approach. There's nothing inaccurate, naive, or wrong about them. (whether you want to consider using a more sophisticated interval lazy is up to you; I'll say that I don't). To answer question number 2, maybe you can tell us why it's crucial in your application to have an interval of this form?

Comment: Thanks @JohnMadden for your comment. It makes sense that these intervals are suitable for positive intervals. It still feels weird to turn them into 6.24 ±  0.7. (more explanation in the next comment)

Comment: Briefly, I'm trying to come up with a new allometric "law" based on some measurements made by me (of the style aM^b) and on what is reported in the literature (also cM^d). For my measurements, I have the confidence intervals of both a and b.  I need to multiply (aM^b)(cM^d) (in fact several operations of products and divisions). And I guess that it should be wise to give the CI of all the operations, and the final allometric expression. I guess I might give more strength to the research (but the truth is that I don't know if it is statistically accustomed - it was suggested by my advisor).

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want to propagate confidence intervals on $a,b$ individually to build a confidence interval on the quantity $aM^b$, right?

Comment: Yes, to the first part. An allometric expression usually has the style $aM^{b}$ (as a function of the body mass $M$). I'm trying to come up with a new one combining different allometric expressions, say:
$P= (cM^d)(fM^g)/(hM^ĵ) = aM^{b}$
in which $a = cf/h$ and $b=d+g-j$. Each coefficient c, d, f, g, h, j has its own CI. Then, I would need to propagate the CI for $a$ and $b$ individually. (However, some old papers report the confidence intervals as in the original question or an upper and lower bound with the mean not being in the middle of both -.- ). Sorry for making this so complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately propagating uncertainty through multiplication and division requires us to know more than just a confidence interval. We're going to have to make some assumptions about the distributions of $c,d,f,g,h,j$. Once we have distributions on those, simulate values of them from their distribution, and then you can compute a sample of $a,b$ which you can then build intervals on.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. Yes, it's hard to know about the distributions of the coefficients and exponents (all that is reported is that they come from linear regression or standard major axis regression). Is it related to Monte Carlo methods or parametric bootstrap? I'll read about it. 
and thank you again for your help.

Comment: I see, in that case we can piggy-back of the distributional assumptions that the regression step made and "outsource" the responsibility of choosing a distribution to those authors. I had Monte Carlo in mind, but a parametric bootstrap is even better (as we less strongly rely on distributional assumptions).

Comment: These confidence intervals by division and multiplication transform into intervals $\pm$ when you take the logarithm. Your combination of the body mass $M$ transforms into a linear combination when taking the logarithm. So maybe you can make your problem simpler by means applying a logarithm,

Comment: Thank you @cdalitz for the suggestion. I did not consider the logarithmic approach, I'll also try that way and see to what I arrive at.

Comment: @JohnMadden, I'll also try the parametric bootstrap, I've been reading a bit about it, but so far it's not that clear to me (I've also been recollecting more data for my research). If you could recommend some bibliography of where to read about, it will be great. Thank you again for all your help!!! ^v^

Comment: @KaleM.F Unfortunately, bootstrap is out of my research area; I'm only familiar with textbooks that treat it, like Elements https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf